# Update different date_format in same column

Tags: mysql

I want to change the column 'date_col' from Varchar to Date (US). 
This column has also datas, but with different Date Format. Here the 3 different date_format:

```
            '2012-02-27'
            '12/05/2013'
            '24-03-2015'
```

I have tried to make an update of all datas before, but it doesn't works. Here the code

```
            UPDATE table SET date_col = STR_TO_DATE(date_col, '%d/%m/%Y')
            WHERE date_col != DATE_FORMAT(date_col, '%Y-%m-%d');
```

Someboddy an Idea?

THX in advance

Comment: He doesn't transform the existing data to the default date_format 'yyyy-mm-dd'

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just do a REGEX match? The string you are looking for will always end with "/xxxx" (four-digit year after "/"), so maybe just match a regex?

Comment: No not always, i have also the day at the end! So i have not every time the same order of numbers

Comment: So just do 3 queries, one for each format... Another piece of advice is that I'd recommend *against* doing a direct update. Create another column, `date_col_staging`, of type `DATE`, and output your reformatted results there. Once you handle all formats and double-check everything, just drop the old column (`date_col`) and rename `date_col_staging` to `date_col`.

Comment: That could be complicated because i have also 24 other columns in the same table. I thought there will be a query to change the date_format directly.

Comment: There might be, but I'm not aware of one (although I'm no MySQL expert)... That's how I would do it. But maybe someone else will answer with a better way. Also, the table having 24 columns shouldn't be a problem, since you're just modifying one column. Just make sure that the staging column is inserted at the correct ordinal/position to make sure that existing queries are not affected.

Comment: Strongly agree with @Ruslan

Comment: you can use "case when" to tell the date format first and use different function to convert different formats.